# Access denied exception | Deployment of ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor Webassembly Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2016, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to deploy ASP.NET Core Hosted Blazor Webassembly Application in a Windows Server 2016 (in AWS).
The application gets hosted without any error in IIS. But while the application reaches the code section related to verifying a certificate instance I get the following exception:

`One or more errors occurred. (Access is denied.)`

I have also tried the same in Windows 10 Pro and the exception is not thrown. In Windows server 2016, I have tried running the application directly using executable and it works as expected and exception is not thrown in this approach.

I have also launched the IIS with administrative privileges and still the issue persists. Does this problem arise due to Windows user access privileges? How can I resolve the above mentioned exception?

Comment: Since we don't know which codes throw this error, we couldn't know this is related with IIS or not. Is there any more details error message that shows which lines throw the access denied error?

Comment: The exception is from my application and it is not from IIS.